# Please add "Return to Question" from the Community Ads into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, localization, international-sites, transifex, community-promotion-ads

In the international SO sites there has been a post where Community Ads can be proposed. In all of them there is a link to the site where *You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria*. None of them has the title 'Return to Question' in their language; instead, it shows in English.

See the pages here:

- SOes [Community Ads 2020](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4713/83)
  → https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/4713
- SOru [Реклама сообщества 2020](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10472/193685)
  → https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/10472
- SOpt [Community Ads 2020](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8338/28073)
  → https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/8338
- SOja [コミュニティ広告の案を募集しています (2020年)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3333/19559)
  → https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/3333

The [string is in traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Return%20to) but it must be used in another place, since the translation does not apply.